# In-app purchase, consumable

Tags: ios, cocoa, in-app

This is a Cocoa in-app purchase question.

I have a game where you can buy a set of 10 lives, and this is a **consumable** in-app purchase -- once the lives are used up, the user must buy more.

What happens if the user uses a subset of the lives, say, 5, and then deletes the app, reinstalls, and restores purchases? Apple will tell the user that they purchased a set of 10 lives, and my program will happily oblige and give them 5 extra lives.

Does my server need to keep track of this data? I haven't found any information in the in-app purchase documentation about how to proceed for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*What happens if the user uses a subset of the lives, say, 5, and then deletes the app, reinstalls, and restores purchases?Apple will tell the user that they purchased a set of 10 lives, and my program will happily oblige and give them 5 extra lives.*

No! the consumable products cannot be restored. Even if you provide a Restore IAP, consumable products cannot be restored back. So your concern that the user will get 5 extra lives is baseless, but yes you need to keep track of the lives that are used by the user if your app is syncing data with server.

Here is what Apple docs say,

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW2

> Consumable products, by their nature, aren’t synced or restored. Users
>   understand that, for example, buying ten more bubbles on their iPhone
>   doesn’t also give them ten more bubbles on their iPad. All other types
>   of products are made available across all of the user’s devices.
>   They’re also restored so users can continue to access their purchased
>   content even after buying a new device. Store Kit handles the syncing
>   and restoring process for auto-renewable and free subscriptions and
>   for non-consumable products.
>
> Products that expire or get used up—consumable products,
>   auto-renewable subscriptions, and non-renewing subscriptions—can be
>   purchased multiple times to get the consumable item again or extend
>   the subscription.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation